# Slide delay for no apparent reason css slider jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so as per the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/013481b9/19/

For the purpose of this question the focus is between the first and second slide transition... when you get to the second transition the classes don't get added immediately on the slide they wait for about 1 second the slider area... Can someone explain why as I want to have the classes added immediately on slide load.

p.s I am using getscript from another part of the site to load the script ... this is the script , (slider-animation.js)..

```
$(function() {
    var $slides = $(".slides");
    $slides.first().addClass("new-class");
    $(".slide-container")
    .on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd", function(e){
        // do something here
        $slides.find(".slide-container [class^='add-anim']").removeClass("animat fadeInUpBig bounceInUp");
        var $radio = $slides.find(":radio[name='radio-btn']:checked");
```

and this is the getscript just after the loading of the slider, (.slides) to another page....

```
$(".tile-area-main").css({width: "720px"}).load("what.html .slides");
      $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ea55zpe3/

Don't forget the line: `overflow: hidden;`in `body`, this gets rid of the scroll bar appearing for a second.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tile-area-main" id="tam-content">
<ul class="slides animated bounceInUp">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slideM">
            <p class="add-anim-up">thisis an area for some text</p>
            <p class="add-anim-left">Thisthis is another text area</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slideM">
            <p class="add-anim-up">some more text to have some classes added to</p>
            <p class="add-anim-up">some more text with something to do</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slideM">
            <div id="referrals" class="add-anim-up">
                <div id="company-title">
                     <h2>Referrals</h2>

                </div>
                <p class="add-anim-up">herapist or speech and language therapist) referrals are accepted, music therapy is unfortunately not currently available on the NHS. Schools are able tssions. If you have any questions or enquiries about musitate to contact us. (contact icon)</p>
            </div>
            <div id="local-links" class="add-anim-up">
                <div id="company-title">
                     <h2>Local Links</h2>

                </div>
                <br/>
                <p class="add-anim-left">MusAbility are always interested in networking and making local links with other businesses, charities and organisations in the North-West. Please send us a message to tell us about yourselves or to arrange to meet for a coffee and a chat (other beverages are accepted!) If you are interested in building a more formal partnership or co-promoting, please get in touch.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slideM">
            <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slideM">
            <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slideM">
            <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:#000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.metro .tile-area-main {
    position: fixed;
    left: 290px;
    top: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 780px;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index : 3000;
}
.metro .tile-area-main p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 2.4em 0.6em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color : #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.slides input {
    display: none;
}
.slide-container {
    display: block;
}
.slideM {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.slideM img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slideM p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size : 22px;
}
.nav {
    z-index:9999;
    top:0;
}
.nav .prev {
    margin-left:-80px
}
.nav .next {
    right: -80px;
}
.nav label {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 56pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family:"Varela Round", sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}
.slideM:hover + .nav label {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.nav label:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
input:checked + .slide-container .slideM {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
input:checked + .slide-container .nav label {
    display: block;
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1000px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 1000px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInUpBig {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1000px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 1000px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}
.fadeInUpBig {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUpBig;
    animation-name: fadeInUpBig;
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.new-class .slideM {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var $slides = $(".slides");
    $slides.first().addClass("new-class");
    $(".add-anim-up").addClass("animated fadeInUpBig bounceInUp");
    $(".add-anim-left").addClass("animated fadeInUpBig bounceInUp");
    $(".nav").on("click", function () {
        $(".add-anim-up").removeClass("animated fadeInUpBig bounceInUp");
        $(".add-anim-left").removeClass("animated fadeInUpBig bounceInUp");
        if ($(".add-anim-up").css('opacity') == '1') {
            $(".add-anim-up").addClass("animated fadeInUpBig bounceInUp");
            $(".add-anim-left").addClass("animated fadeInUpBig bounceInUp");

        };
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response , but the fiddle you just linked actually contains no text on the 2nd slide at all ?

Comment: just checking it against another animation , one sec mate

Comment: ok check this one out , http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/013481b9/27/ with the bounceinup animation it presents the text then does it , arrrg

Comment: I am quite certain it is because the transition end point is at a point where you can see the text on the next slide , I was thinking that maybe the on.("transitionend"... bit needs to be replaced by an onlick of the button from the previous slide but i am not sure how to do that

Comment: hey buddy yeah it seems to work , I am just trying it with the bounceInUp class as that was the one that also seemed to cause issues

Comment: i couldn't get it to work , in order for the effect to work you also have to include the class "animated" ,... i did this but doesn't seem to work

Comment: It does haha, but I merged "animated" and "fadeInUpBig". Any way will work, I changed the link above, try that one. That should solve everything.

Comment: hah ! awesome , the jsfiddle works so I am giving you the answer regardless , will try and get this integrated into my project thanks so much for helping mate

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

If you switch your removeClass to after the addClass statements, you shouldn't see this behavior (http://jsfiddle.net/013481b9/25/):

```
var $radio = $slides.find(":radio[name='radio-btn']:checked");

$radio.next(".slide-container").find(".add-anim-up").addClass("animated fadeInUpBig");

$radio.next(".slide-container").find(".add-anim-left").addClass("animated fadeInUpBig");

$slides.find(".slide-container [class^='add-anim']").removeClass("animated fadeInUpBig bounceInUp");
```

The pause/flicker you were seeing was the classes being removed before the next animation was added.

Another thing I noticed (but that was not causing this specific behavior) was that the `transitionend` event was being run multiple times (for each change css change to the box), so I added a check for the `transform` event:

```
if (e.originalEvent.propertyName == 'transform') {
    // do stuff
}
```

Hopefully that's helpful. Best of luck!

Comment: I am certain that is helpful thanks very much for your response, I am trying it now

Comment: thank again , i put the code in but it still seems to present the text before applying the animation... i am now using bounceinup instead of the fadeupbig

Comment: ok check this one out , jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/013481b9/27 with the bounceinup animation it presents the text then does it , arrrg

Comment: I am quite certain it is because the transition end point is at a point where you can see the text on the next slide , I was thinking that maybe the on.("transitionend"... bit needs to be replaced by an onlick of the button from the previous slide but i am not sure how to do that